# Replace row within a df if other row from a group is equal to 1 [R]

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe such as :

```
Names COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
SP1   0    1    NaN  LA
SP1   0    1    NaN  LE
SP1   0    1    1    LI
SP2   1    0    0    LO
SP2   0    0    0    LU
SP3   1    1    NaN  LY
SP3   1    1    NaN  LZ
```

And I would like for each group of `Names`, to replace for each `COL1`, `COL2` and `COL3` values `0` or `NaN` when another row within a column is equal to `1`.

For example in the Group `SP1`:

```
Names COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
SP1   0    1    NaN  LA
SP1   0    1    NaN  LE
SP1   0    1    1    LI
```

As you can see in the `COL3` there are two `NaN`, and one `1` value, so since there is at least on `1` value, I transform the two `NaN` into a `1`:

```
Names COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
SP1   0    1    1    LA
SP1   0    1    1    LE
SP1   0    1    1    LI
```

Same for the group `SP2`:

```
Names COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
SP2   1    0    0    LO
SP2   0    0    0    LU
```

As you can see in the `COL1` there are one `0`, and one `1` value, so since there is at least on `1` value, I transform the `0` into a `1`:

```
Names COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
SP2   1    0    0    LO
SP2   1    0    0    LU
```

---

At the end I should then get :

```
Names COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
SP1   0    1    1    LA
SP1   0    1    1    LE
SP1   0    1    1    LI
SP2   1    0    0    LO
SP2   1    0    0    LU
SP3   1    1    NaN  LY
SP3   1    1    NaN  LZ
```

Here is the dput format of the example df :

```
structure(list(Names = c("SP1", "SP1", "SP1", "SP2", "SP2", "SP3", 
"SP3"), COL1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), COL2 = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), COL3 = c(NaN, NaN, 1, 0, 0, NaN, NaN), COL4 = c("LA", 
"LE", "LI", "LO", "LU", "LY", "LZ")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

---

Comment: It is not clear what you would like to do here, could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I updated by commenting the example

Comment: Oh I see. So it's simply a case of replacing zero values of a column with 1 in each group right?

Comment: If 1 is present in that group for a specific column yes, as you can see in group SP3 for the COL3, there is only NaN, so I do not replace them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After grouping by 'Names', create a condition with `if/else` to do the `replace`ment i.e. if `1` is present `%in%` the column, `replace` the `NaN` or `0` with `1`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
   group_by(Names) %>%
   mutate(across(COL1:COL3, ~ if(1 %in% .x) replace(.x, is.nan(.x)|
          .x %in% 0, 1) else .x)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 5
  Names  COL1  COL2  COL3 COL4 
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 SP1       0     1     1 LA   
2 SP1       0     1     1 LE   
3 SP1       0     1     1 LI   
4 SP2       1     0     0 LO   
5 SP2       1     0     0 LU   
6 SP3       1     1   NaN LY   
7 SP3       1     1   NaN LZ
```

Comment: how can I replace across(COL1:COL3 ... by a list of column name ?

Comment: @chippycentra if you have `nm1 <- c("COL1", "COL2", "COL3")` then in `across` you need `across(all_of(nm1), ~ if(..`

Comment: Hi, thanks, I juste edited my question to show you the problem I'm facing with your code.

Comment: Oh ok, I have NA not NaN sorry for that !

Comment: @chippycentra `is.na` returns TRUE for both NaN and NA, whereas `is.nan` is TRUE only for NaN (I am using R 4.2.2).  So you may need to change `is.nan` to `is.na`